# Can not find reason for crash test flight

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, testflight

Just one of my test flight beta testers has reported a crash. I have for 2 months now been scratching my head as to why it crashes for them and no others. I am unable to replicate the crash myself so have to submit a new build through the test flight system with iTunes connect and wait for user to test it before I know if I have made progress or not. This is very slow and tedious process and so I am here to plead you for your knowledge and help me first understand why the app crashes only for this one user (of 12) .

The crash report I get from test flight is

```
> Incident Identifier: 64F2AB18-E3F4-48A2-A865-CCAB2FF2BF12
Beta Identifier:     5E64ED31-B493-4406-94E5-E4233A84D2A6
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             anAppName [2491]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C971485-F0ED-4CA0-96F7-AF9EA7A71A30/anAppName.app/anAppName
Identifier:          com.aCleverName.anAppName
Version:             1.0.9.8.1 (1.0)
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-16 11:39:04.04 +0100
Launch Time:         2015-10-16 11:38:54.54 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000d6b24
Triggered by Thread:  0

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.467279     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f919a4 TCP Conn 0x1545fb500 SSL Handshake DONE
0.722080     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f918b4 TCP Conn 0x1545fb500 starting SSL negotiation
0.722520     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184033760 TCP Conn 0x1545fb500 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
0.723794     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034c8c TCP Conn 0x1545fb500 event 1. err: 0
0.761090     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034d64 TCP Conn 0x1545fb500 started
0.764039     CFNetwork                  0x000000018408a5a4 Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
0.764039     CFNetwork                  0x000000018408a570 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
0.764039     CFNetwork                  0x00000001840dc498 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
6.422985     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018bb02348 [0x1550bb000] Created session
6.435154     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018bb02348 [0x15487f600] Created session
6.480890     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018bb02348 [0x1550c1000] Created session
6.952666     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f919a4 TCP Conn 0x1546a5230 SSL Handshake DONE
7.034320     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f918b4 TCP Conn 0x1546a5230 starting SSL negotiation
7.035121     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184033760 TCP Conn 0x1546a5230 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
7.036622     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034c8c TCP Conn 0x1546a5230 event 1. err: 0
7.607332     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034d64 TCP Conn 0x1546a5230 started
7.726344     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f919a4 TCP Conn 0x154670e50 SSL Handshake DONE
7.868298     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f919a4 TCP Conn 0x1546408d0 SSL Handshake DONE
7.877690     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f918b4 TCP Conn 0x154670e50 starting SSL negotiation
7.878310     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184033760 TCP Conn 0x154670e50 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
7.879900     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034c8c TCP Conn 0x154670e50 event 1. err: 0
7.979690     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f918b4 TCP Conn 0x1546408d0 starting SSL negotiation
7.981042     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184033760 TCP Conn 0x1546408d0 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
7.982874     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034c8c TCP Conn 0x1546408d0 event 1. err: 0
8.939527     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034d64 TCP Conn 0x154670e50 started
9.065458     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184034d64 TCP Conn 0x1546408d0 started

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   anAppName                       0x00000001000d6b24 specialized MeetUpsListDisplayTableViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (MeetUpsListDisplayTableViewController.swift:141)
1   anAppName                       0x00000001000d48f0 @objc MeetUpsListDisplayTableViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (MeetUpsListDisplayTableViewController.swift:0)
2   UIKit                           0x000000018a125660 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 688
3   UIKit                           0x000000018a1257b8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
4   UIKit                           0x000000018a1153b8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2440
5   UIKit                           0x000000018a12a348 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 104
6   UIKit                           0x0000000189ecba74 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
7   UIKit                           0x0000000189ddeff0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 644
8   QuartzCore                      0x00000001895e5f14 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
9   QuartzCore                      0x00000001895e0b20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001895e09e0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001895e007c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001895dfdd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 516
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001895d94bc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184843c30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001848419d4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184841e04 __CFRunLoopRun + 928
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184770dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
18  GraphicsServices                0x000000018f8c4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
19  UIKit                           0x0000000189e4af44 UIApplicationMain + 204
20  anAppName                       0x0000000100118ef4 main (AppDelegate.swift:19)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000199bbe8b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdbc0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdc59c kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000199ba0a04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000199b8f93c _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdbc0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdbc0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdbc0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cc0c30 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cc0aac mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184844168 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184841e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184770dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018400e074 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x00000001857cb138 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da3b3c _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da3aa0 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1030 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdb408 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018484a6d0 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da3b3c _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da3aa0 _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1030 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdbc0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199cdbc0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199da1028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000101315400   x1: 0x0000000199d9a8f4   x2: 0x0000000000000050   x3: 0x0000000199d08674
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000033   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000101315408   x9: 0x0000000000000005  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000a00
   x12: 0x0000000000000040  x13: 0x0000000000000009  x14: 0x0000000000904810  x15: 0x0000000155a00000
   x16: 0x0000000199d08178  x17: 0x00000001001905e0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001548acc00
   x20: 0x0000000000000008  x21: 0x0000000000000010  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000020
   x24: 0x0000000000000040  x25: 0x0000000000000200  x26: 0x0000000100458a40  x27: 0x0000000000000420
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd813f0   lr: 0x00000001000d5f1c
    sp: 0x000000016fd81210   pc: 0x00000001000d6b24 cpsr: 0x80000000

Binary Images: ...
```

And the code

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

let locationsManager = CLLocationManager()

var usersLocation = CLLocation()

var flag : Bool!

class MeetUpsListDisplayTableViewController : UITableViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var meetUpsJSON = [NSDictionary]()
var userLocation : CLLocation?

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
print("failed with error :\(error)")
locationsManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

usersLocation = locations.last!

let usersCoordinates = CLGeocoder()
usersCoordinates.reverseGeocodeLocation(usersLocation) { ( placemark : [CLPlacemark]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

if error == nil {

self.fetchEventsInUsersCountry((placemark?.last?.ISOcountryCode)!)
locationsManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}else{
print(error)
}
}

locationsManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}


func fetchEventsInUsersCountry( countryISO : String ){

let components = NSURLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "www.website.com"
components.path = "/TMVUKApp/findEvents.php"
components.query = "usersISOCountryCode=\(countryISO)"

let fetchEventsURL = components.URL!
print(fetchEventsURL)

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: fetchEventsURL)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

(data, response, error) -> Void in

if error == nil{

self.meetUpsJSON = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! [NSDictionary]

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {


if self.meetUpsJSON.count > 0 {

self.tableView.reloadData()

}
}
}

}

task.resume()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()


self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MeetUpDisplayTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "meetUp")
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero) 

//************************** GEtting User's latitude/ Longitude ********************

locationsManager.delegate = self
locationsManager.startUpdatingLocation()

//************************** GEtting User's latitude/ Longitude ********************






// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

print("noris")

return self.meetUpsJSON.count
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

print("cfraip")

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("meetUp", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MeetUpDisplayTableViewCell
//  
//  ///meetUpsJSON is array of dictionaries.

let JSONDict = meetUpsJSON[indexPath.row]


let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

if let eventDateString = JSONDict["EventDateTime"] as? String {
let eventDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(eventDateString)
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let components : NSDateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Year,NSCalendarUnit.Month,NSCalendarUnit.Day,NSCalendarUnit.Hour,NSCalendarUnit.Minute,NSCalendarUnit.Weekday], fromDate: eventDate!)

cell.lblCalendarDateDisplay.text = "\(components.day)"

var dayOfWeek : String?
var monthOfYear : String?

switch (components.weekday){
case 1:
dayOfWeek = "Sun"

case 2:
dayOfWeek = "Mon"

case 3:
dayOfWeek = "Tue"

case 4:
dayOfWeek = "Wed"

case 5:
dayOfWeek = "Thu"

case 6:
dayOfWeek = "Fri"

case 7:
dayOfWeek = "Sat"


default:
print("hit deafult")
}

switch (components.month){
case 1:
monthOfYear = "Jan"

case 2:
monthOfYear = "Feb"

case 3:
monthOfYear = "Mar"

case 4:
monthOfYear = "Apr"

case 5:
monthOfYear = "May"

case 6:
monthOfYear = "Jun"

case 7:
monthOfYear = "Jul"

case 8:
monthOfYear = "Aug"

case 9:
monthOfYear = "Sep"

case 10:
monthOfYear = "Oct"

case 11:
monthOfYear = "Nov"

case 12:
monthOfYear = "Dec"

default:
print("hit default")
}


cell.lblCalendarDayDisplay.text = dayOfWeek!
cell.lblCalendarMonthYearDisplay.text = "\(monthOfYear!) '\(components.year % 100)"
}

if let eventName = JSONDict["EventName"] as? String{
cell.lblEventNameDisplay.text = eventName
}


cell.vwCalendarDisplay.layer.borderWidth = 1

cell.vwCalendarDisplay.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

if let eventTown = JSONDict["EventTown"] as? String{

cell.lblEventStatusDisplay.text = eventTown //?? ""
}

let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: usersLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: usersLocation.coordinate.longitude)
let eventLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (JSONDict["EventLattitudeCoordinate"] as! NSString).doubleValue, longitude: (JSONDict["EventLongitudeCoordinate"] as! NSString).doubleValue)
let usersDistanceToEventInMeters = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(eventLocation)
let usersDistanceToEventInMiles = usersDistanceToEventInMeters * 0.000621371192
/// let usersDistanceToEventInKiloMeters = usersDistanceToEventInMeters / 1000
cell.lblEventDistanceDisplay.text = Int(usersDistanceToEventInMiles).description



return cell



}
```

The line indicated by crash report is

> let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("meetUp",
>   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MeetUpDisplayTableViewCell

Can you see the reason from this crash log?
What does "specialised" mean?

Thanks so much for any help

If you have to vote this question down. Well done you. But please be brave enough to say why

UPDATE:
So I installed fabrics crashlytics and peppered my code my logs to find out where exactly i was crashing. From the logs it appears I am crashing as soon as I try to set a property of the cell. This though as mentioned is only an issue for one user. Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: The crash is on line 141 of MeetUpsListDisplayTableViewController.swift. If you show us that code, maybe we can help in more detail.

Comment: I appologies for the poor formatting of my post. I'm trying to highlight the code part to place in correct tags but on a mobile device and apples UIMenuController is useless

Comment: Why don't you use Crashlytics from fabric?
It will you crash report in detail even file name, method name and Line of code...

Comment: @MrugeshTank thanks I will do that

Comment: You won't get a better crash report from Crashlytics than the one you have, so talking about Crashlytics is off-topic.

Comment: Ok I installed Crashlytics and whilst its too early to know what the crash reporting is like the fact that I can get a test build to beta testers in seconds rather that waiting hours sometimes for apple to process it in test flight, I'm never using test flight again! Thanks @MrugeshTank

Comment: Try setting the compiler optimization to lower level.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NikolayNankov what would that do?

Comment: @RyanForsyth I recently had a similar problem where I can't figure out why declaring a let sometimes crashes the code. Lowering how fierce the optimization of the code is during compilation solved my problem... I don't know exactly why but it did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

After using Fabrics Crashlytics and going line by line I discovered that the app was crashing here

```
      let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

//changed this
    //dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
//to
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")

    if let eventDateString = JSONDict["EventDateTime"] as? String {
    let eventDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(eventDateString)
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components : NSDateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Year,NSCalendarUnit.Month,NSCalendarUnit.Day,NSCalendarUnit.Hour,NSCalendarUnit.Minute,NSCalendarUnit.Weekday], fromDate: eventDate!)
```

long story short the crash occurs when users device is using the 12 hour format and not 24 hour.

Comment: What did you change the code here to to make it work?

Comment: Changed the commented code for the code below it. see updated answer.

Comment: This solved my problem as well. This was a headache that must have lasted a month for me. The crash logs were almost useless.